# Calculate the difference in milliseconds between 2 given time

Tags: bash, shell

I have a log and in this log I have this times:
14:03:26,599
14:03:26,788
14:03:26,924
14:03:27,125

How calculate the difference between two of theses times in milliseconds?
I tryed:

```
LOGTIME1=14:03:26,599
LOGTIME2=14:03:26,788
CONVERT1=$(date +d $LOGTIME1 +%s.%N)
CONVERT2=$(date +d $LOGTIME1 +%s.%N)
TOTAL=$(CONVERT2 - CONVERT1)
```

But I do not get this to work.
I recive the error: date: extra operand ‘14:03:26,599’
I belive is because "," and 599...
But I do not know how handle it.

Comment: It's `-d`, not `+d`. Also, you probably meant `TOTAL=$((...))` instead of `$(...)`.

Comment: tnks, i will fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
bc -l <<< "$(date -d "$LOGTIME2" '+%s.%N') - $(date -d "$LOGTIME1" '+%s.%N')"

.189000000
```

Note that you have to use `-d` in `date` and use `bc -l` for floating point arithmetic and bash only does integer arithmetic.